# Sails.js: error logging in with passport

Tags: sails.js, passport.js

When this part of my code gets executed:

```
req.login(user, function (err){
    if (err) return res.negotiate(err);
    return res.redirect('/welcome');
});
```

I get the following error:

```
/home/oriol/Desktop/containers/node_modules/sails-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:98
    process.nextTick(function() { throw err; });
                                  ^

Error: passport.initialize() middleware not in use
    at IncomingMessage.req.login.req.logIn (/home/oriol/Desktop/containers/node_modules/passport-local/node_modules/passport/lib/passport/http/request.js:30:30)
    at /home/oriol/Desktop/containers/api/controllers/AuthController.js:37:15
    at wrapper (/home/oriol/Desktop/containers/node_modules/lodash/index.js:3592:19)
    at applyInOriginalCtx (/home/oriol/Desktop/containers/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/utils/normalize.js:421:80)
    at wrappedCallback (/home/oriol/Desktop/containers/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/utils/normalize.js:324:18)
    at success (/home/oriol/Desktop/containers/node_modules/waterline/node_modules/switchback/lib/normalize.js:33:31)
    at _switch (/home/oriol/Desktop/containers/node_modules/waterline/node_modules/switchback/lib/factory.js:58:28)
    at /home/oriol/Desktop/containers/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/query/dql/create.js:248:9
    at /home/oriol/Desktop/containers/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:52:16
    at /home/oriol/Desktop/containers/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:269:32
    at /home/oriol/Desktop/containers/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:44:16
    at child.<anonymous> (/home/oriol/Desktop/containers/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/utils/schema.js:152:44)
    at fn (/home/oriol/Desktop/containers/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/utils/callbacksRunner.js:60:10)
    at /home/oriol/Desktop/containers/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:181:20
    at iterate (/home/oriol/Desktop/containers/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:262:13)
    at Object.async.forEachOfSeries.async.eachOfSeries (/home/oriol/Desktop/containers/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:281:9)
    at Object.async.forEachSeries.async.eachSeries (/home/oriol/Desktop/containers/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:214:22)
    at Object.runner.afterCreate (/home/oriol/Desktop/containers/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/utils/callbacksRunner.js:63:9)
    at after (/home/oriol/Desktop/containers/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/query/dql/create.js:243:17)
    at /home/oriol/Desktop/containers/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/query/dql/create.js:230:68
    at wrapper (/home/oriol/Desktop/containers/node_modules/lodash/index.js:3592:19)
    at applyInOriginalCtx (/home/oriol/Desktop/containers/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/utils/normalize.js:421:80)
```

I have read other posts about the same issue but none of them seems to fix it. I don't know much about why is this happening, feel free to ask for further explanation or any piece of code that might be relevant. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I just found out now how to solve that. This question can be closed.

I did this for the second time and somehow it worked: [Sails.js + Passport.js: passport.initialize() middleware not in use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33106986/sails-js-passport-js-passport-initialize-middleware-not-in-use).